# Testing altcoin reward halving - Help!

Tags: block, altcoin, mining-reward, reward-schedule

I am currently working on reward halving changes for a test coin and i have added all the necessary changes but my question is how do i safely test this new halving without affecting production. I understand bitcoin has testnet but is there a way to test the altcoin halving. May be connecting two daemons with each other to create a closed network? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your test coin source code has the same regtest mode as bitcoin, you can use that, it allows you to mine blocks instantly and it's a completely separate chain to the testnet or mainnet so it won't affect anyone else. You can run your coin with the `-regtest` argument, and then use the `generate` RPC to mine blocks and see how much reward you get. Note that in the source code, the regtest reward halving may be (and probably is) a different number of blocks to mainnet, this can be changed in `chainparams.cpp`

Comment: Hi MeshCollider thank you for your answer but i am afraid i cannot use -regtest as the source code is not the same.